# SVG looking for an inverse drawing style (xor pen)

Tags: svg

Is there an 'inverse drawing style' implemented in SVG? I simulate what I mean in the snippet, but that's not a proper way of doing it when things get more complicated. For instance when you want to draw a 'rubber box' (or selection box) or you want to make calibration crosses.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g stroke-width="10" fill="none">
   <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" /> 
   <line x1="100" y1="25" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" /> 
   <line x1="100" y1="45" x2="100" y2="55" stroke="white" /> 
   <line x1="100" y1="55" x2="100" y2="155" stroke="black" /> 
   <line x1="100" y1="155" x2="100" y2="145" stroke="white" /> 
   <line x1="100" y1="175" x2="100" y2="155" stroke="black" /> 
</g>
</svg>
```

In this example it should have been 1 line in invert modus in stead of 5 lines simulating it.

This kind of invert drawing you find in many programming environments. It would surprise me if it wasn't implemented in SVG. But so far, I didn't find it. I tried to simulate more complicated ones using javascript, but even then it is not easy, since there is no way of probing the color at a certain point, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Shape elements like`<path>` and `<polygon>`, and text content elements support a [`fill-rule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) presentation attribute that computes what is inside and outside of a single path in two different ways. That makes it possible to define your example like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 40" width="40%">
  <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M 4,9 H 26 V 31 H 4 Z M 24,29 H 6 V 11 H 24 Z M 14,5 H 16 V 35 H 14 Z" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 40" width="40%">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 4,9 H 26 V 31 H 4 Z M 24,29 H 6 V 11 H 24 Z M 14,5 H 16 V 35 H 14 Z" />
</svg>
```

Results for the `nonzero` value will differ depending on subpaths being drawn in clockwise or anti-clockwise direction.

Note you cannot apply this attribute to describe the intersection of multiple elements; they always apply to only one element or glyph. Similarily, it describes fills and has no effect on the rendering of strokes.

Comment: That’s not what’s it about. I am looking for a xor pen, that inverts the color beneath what it is printed on. It makes sure, someting ‘printed’ is always visible no matter where it is printed, on top of any other color, you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give some more explanation for what I am looking for, what my question is about, and show you a possible go-around or circumvention.
By the way: **invert mode** is also known as **xor pen**.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg  width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 50" 
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   onload="init()">
   <script>
   var mc = {}, wp = {}; // mycross, whitepart
   var x = 5, intervalID = 0;
   function init() {
      mc = document.getElementById("mycross");
      wp = document.getElementById("whitepart");
      setTimeout(doloop, 1500);   
   }
   function doloop() {
      if (intervalID!=0) return;
      intervalID = setInterval(loop,30);    
   }
   function loop() {
      mc.setAttribute("x",x); x += 0.25;
      if(x>75) { 
         clearInterval(intervalID); intervalID = 0; 
         if(wp.getAttribute("style") == "display:none") {
            x = 5; mc.setAttribute("x",x);
            wp.setAttribute("style","display:inline-block");
            setTimeout(doloop, 1500); 
         } else {wp.setAttribute("style","display:none"); }
      };
   }
   </script>
   <defs>
      <g id="cross" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:0.264583, 0.264583;stroke-dashoffset:0;">>
         <g stroke="black">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5"/>
            <line x1="0" y1="10" x2= "20" y2="10" />
            <line x1="10" y1="0" x2= "10" y2="20" />
         </g>
         <g id="whitepart" stroke="white" transform="translate(0.1 0.1)" style="display:none">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5"/>
            <line x1="0" y1="10" x2= "20" y2="10" />
            <line x1="10" y1="0" x2= "10" y2="20" />
         </g>
      </g>
   </defs>
   
   <g fill="none" stroke="black">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="2" stroke-width="2.5" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="10" stroke-width="5" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="20" stroke-width="7.5" />
   </g>
   
   <use id="mycross" x="5" y="15" xlink:href="#cross" />
</svg>
```

In this example above I suppose the purpose of an invert modus is clearer.

The first time the 'cross' passes, it is not 'inverted' (nor simulated). So where the 'cross' passes over a black surface, you cannot see it anymore. If you had a real invert mode or xor pen: on white it would be black, on black it would be white. Where ever the cross is, then you can see it.

The second time the cross passes, I added a 'layer' with the same cross in white, translated or shifted 0.1 points.
This is a circumvention, and like they all do, they ask more work or programming and might get you in trouble in some cases. A simple xor pen would make it easier to handle.

(most recent adaptation makes it work in Safari too - besides FireFox, Chrome, MS Edge)

Comment: If I knew how to delete, I would. I only see a flag "Vote to delete this post"... Now, I made a better version, with a go-around 'solution'. Hope that's ok now?

Comment: Just [edit] this to make more obvious how this is a solution to the question, according to [answer], then you should be safe. Or delete this and edit the question to add this as an example of what seems like a solution, with an explanation of why it is not. But do not use an answer to extend the questions info.

Comment: The snippet speaks for itself, at least in Chrome, Firefox, MS Edge... But not in Safari on iPad I just saw(surprise, surprise). There, the second pass still goes 'behind' the black circles and it is also much slower (milliseconds are not the same in Safari?). That is the trouble with workarounds or circumventions. Much more difficult to get it right everywhere all the time. A real xor pen in SVG would be so much easier. So my question remains, yes. Still, if the semi-solution already works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, it is worth showing, or not?

Comment: I think so, it should be accepted as a partial answer, i.e. solving at least a part of the problem. I think that applies here. You probably want to move all that interesting info from the comment into the answer post however. And I recommend to explicitly state that this solves part, though not all of it. Most experienced StackOverflow users probably know the partially official term "partial answer" so you might want to use it, but just say plainly what you mean this to be. You can also put something into the question like "As you see below, I only found a partial solution...".

Comment: Found a way to make it work in Safari too... Cannot post it as an answer. Have to wait for 13h until I am allowed. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: Are you sure that it requires a separate answer? If it is a different approach, a different idea, then I agree. But if it is an adaption of this solution to Safari it might be just a targeted part of this answer, though there is no reason to squeeze it in here. Have fun. Good luck.